# Rails truncate strings in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, truncate, acts-as-taggable-on

In my app I'm trying to truncate a string of tags that get displayed. I've tried doing it this way:

```
<%= @medium.marker_list.map { |m| 
      link_to truncate('+ ' + m.titleize, length: 5), 
              :controller => "media", :action => "index", :media => m 
    }.join(' ').html_safe %>
```

The problem is that if any string is greater than 5 it replaces the whole string with ellipsis instead of replacing just the characters that are longer than the set length.

How do I get this to output correctly?

I'm creating the tags through the acts-as-taggable gem.

** **EDIT** **

So if I have list of tags like this: `example, test, product, listing`

it returns this: `..., test, ..., ...`

when it should be returning this: `examp...,test,produ..., listi...`

Comment: Please provide an example list of tags, the output you are getting, and the output you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
%w(example test product listing).map { |w| w.size > 5 ? w[0,5] + "..." : w }
```

Output:

```
[examp..., test, produ..., listi...]
```

So in your code you could implement that like this (untested):

```
# Helper method
def truncate_tag(tag)
  tag.size > 5 ? tag[0,5] + "..." : tag
end

# View
<%= @medium.marker_list.map { |m|
    link_to truncate_tag(m.titleize),
    :controller => "media",
    :action => "index",
    :media => m
}.join(' ').html_safe %>
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I think it should be `w.size > 5` otherwise five-letter words will have ellipses as well.  ("bread" becomes "bread...")

Comment: How would I use this in my `link_to`? I did this `<%= medium.marker_list.map { |m| link_to '+ ' + m.titleize, {:controller => "media", :action => "index", :media => m}, m.size > 5 ? m[0,5] + "..." : m }.join(' ').html_safe %>` but it throws out this error: `undefined method 'stringify_keys' for "examp...":String`

Answer (score 0):

How about going for a simple ruby solution

```
<%= @medium.marker_list.map { |m| 
      link_to "+ {m.titalize}".gsub("+ {m.titalize}"[5..-1],"..."), 
              :controller => "media", :action => "index", :media => m 
    }.join(' ').html_safe %>
```